# Filtering link tracing/checking from click data extracts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, data-extract

In early February, my company noticed a significant uptick in click activity in our data extracts.  Deliveries, opens, bounces, and everything else remained normal.  I opened a ticket with SFMC support, and they attributed this to a general increase in link checking, in addition to a specific trend they started noticing around that time with users using Outlook2003.  They said other clients have reported the same issue, but offered to solution or workaround.

So here's the question - has anyone else experienced this?  What did you do to filter out the bogus clicks?  Should we be exporting are clicks in some other way beside data extracts?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Only thing I can think of is excluding the outlook domain from your export.  Unfortunately, that doesn't identify whether they're actually using Outlook as their email client, nor what version they're using.  You're metrics will naturally be depressed, if you go that route.